# bootstrap npm installation dependecies error in npm

Tags: npm, bootstrap-4, npm-install

This is what I am getting when I am trying to install Bootstrap in my machine with npm:

[image]

This is what I am getting when I installed latest `jquery` and `popper.js`:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **before posting questions**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootstrap npm module has a dependency on `jQuery` and `popper.js` npm modules.

In case you pull the [Bootstrap package](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) from git (`git clone https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git`), the `package.json` of the project will already contain these dependencies under the [`peerDependencies`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/package.json#L206) key.
However, when you install it directly with npm, you have to have these dependencies at hand too. You can use the following command to overcome this:

```
npm install jquery@1.9.1 popper.js@^1.12.9 bootstrap
```

Answer (score 1):

install latest jquery and popper.js via npm and then try the same code

Comment: I Posted an image in question , What exactly I am getting when I try to install latest jquery and popper.js. Please go through that.

Comment: remove npm and try a fresh install of npm .for which platform you are using node